# What are these pathways called in Biology?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

Considering the [pentose phosphate pathway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentose_phosphate_pathway) and the [sulfate reduction pathway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissimilatory_sulfate_reduction) in bacteria;

What are these types of reactions called in biology? Bio degradation reactions or bio transformation reactions or something else? I wish to know whether there is a generalized names for these types of pathways.

Comment: They usually have specific names - your example is the pentose-phosphate way (or pathway).

Comment: is there no generalized names for such pathways?

Comment: If you want it short: Pathway. Otherwise you could think about metabolic pathways or the specific names.

Comment: so these types of chained reaction like pathways have no special names...

Comment: The special names of these chained reaction like pathways is `metabolic pathways`. This is it. For the first time in science, something actually has an intuitive name.

Comment: Metabolism is the term for all biochemical reactions. Degradative pathways (big to small molecules) are called catabolism and constructive pathways are called anabolism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**
Assuming you wish to have a common name for both of these (widely differing!) pathways I basically agree with @Chris, and I would go for general terminology, namely **metabolic pathways**.

**Background**
The [pentose-phosphate pathway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentose_phosphate_pathway) is neither anabolic nor catabolic so those terms won't do. The pentose-phosphate pathway is, however, closely linked to general metabolism to supply the body with C<sub>5</sub> sugars. So metabolic pathway sounds right to me.

The other pathway is a sulfate reduction pathway, which is an [anaerobic respiration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissimilatory_sulfate_reduction) pathway that uses sulfate as the terminal electron acceptor instead of oxygen. It is an *entirely different pathway*. However, it too is neither catabolic or anabolic, but still closely linked to metabolism. Hence, metabolic pathway is applicable here too.